# nested case when with count and math expression

Tags: sql-server, count, case

how can I achieve this result below?

| id | id_status | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | X | 62.5% |
| 15 | Y | 37.5% |

having tried this

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(tab.id) AS id,
  tab.status AS id_status,
  (CASE 
     WHEN tab.status = 'X' THEN (25/40) * 100 -- this is where I'm stucked (40 = total of ids)
     WHEN tab.status = 'Y' THEN 100 - ((25/40) * 100)
     END AS rate
FROM table AS tab
WHERE tab.status in ('X', 'Y')
GROUP BY ROLLUP (tab.status)
```

Comment: Hi @mignoncharly - Check this please https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to see how to post questions and help us to help you receive correct and quick answers.

Comment: Which database are you using? (Read the description for the SQL tag for more information.)

Comment: @MatBailie MS SQL

Comment: Please tag your question with that, as per the description of the SQL tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function to get total count

```
select count(tab.id) as id,
      tab.status as id_status,
      200.0 * count(tab.id) / sum(count(*)) over(order by status rows  between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as rate    
from your_table tab
where tab.status in ('X', 'Y')
group by rollup(tab.status)
```

Note explicit window specification because the default is generally `.. and current row` and 200 because `rollup` will add the total row.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=06982457dcbea774e45a607b760adf6a)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Serg but it doesnt work and the answer seems complicated to understand for me.
```error: COUNT isnt a recognized built-in function name (rather weird )```

Comment: @LearningPath, see the fiddle

Comment: seems to work. I dont know why it doesnt work for me!

Comment: @LearningPath, it should work on any supported versions of MS Sql Server, 2014+